# How to use webEngineView.setHtml twice in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a html page in my window and I would like display a different page when a thread is finished running. Problem is, when the thread is done it crashes the window. So my question, is it possible to run webEngineView.setHtml 2 times without crashing the app?

```
import threading, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5 import QtTest

class win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(win, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.page()

        def update():
            QtTest.QTest.qWait(2000)
            self.page1()

        threading.Thread(target=update, daemon=True).start()

    def page(self):

        h1 = '''
        <html>
        <body>
        '''
        var = "text"
        h2 = '''
        </body>
        </html>'''

        self.webEngineView.setHtml(h1+var+h2)

    def page1(self):
        h1 = '''
        <html>
        <body>
        '''
        var = "updated text"
        h2 = '''
        </body>
        </html>'''

        self.webEngineView.setHtml(h1+var+h2)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = win()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already in countless posts it has been pointed out that the GUI should not be modified from another thread, and clearly you are trying to do so. And the solution always follows the same path: use the signals.

```py
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


def page():

    h1 = """
        <html>
        <body>
        """
    var = "text"
    h2 = """
        </body>
        </html>"""

    return h1 + var + h2


def page1():
    h1 = """
        <html>
        <body>
        """
    var = "updated text"
    h2 = """
        </body>
        </html>"""
    return h1 + var + h2


class Worker(QObject):
    htmlChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def execute(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.task, daemon=True).start()

    def task(self):
        QThread.msleep(2 * 1000)
        html = page1()
        self.htmlChanged.emit(html)


class win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(win, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.webEngineView.setHtml(page())

        worker = Worker(self)
        worker.htmlChanged.connect(self.webEngineView.setHtml)
        worker.execute()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = win()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```