# Update html content in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, html, qt, qwebengineview

I can not get this code working and show into the app the new html after the first html load.

Here are the files to make the tests.

Offtopic:

This is an extra text to allow the submit of this question, please do not waste your time reading this.

stackoverflow, can you submit the question please?

My goodness, I have to keep typing because it keeps saying that I should provide more details. I can not figure out what other details are needed here. I am sure that with enough words written here the post will be allowed to be submitted. Not yet, I will keep on writing. More? Why not? I have spend so much time with this problem for an application I am developing that I do not know what else to do.

If you solve this problem, you will make me very happy.

End of offtopic.

example.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import time


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        self.loadPage()

        vbox.addWidget(self.webEngineView)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('QWebEngineView')
        self.show()

    def loadPage(self):

        with open('test.html', 'r') as f:

            html = f.read()
            self.webEngineView.setHtml(html)



    def loadPage2(self):

        with open('test2.html', 'r') as f:

            html = f.read()
            self.webEngineView.stop()
            self.webEngineView.setHtml(html)
            self.webEngineView.reload() #this line does not update the view



def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    time.sleep(5)
    ex.loadPage2() # I expected to make this a refresh into the interface with the new content.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expected to load the new test2.html into the interface, but it keeps with the first html load.

The test files are:

test.html

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a test 1.</p>

</body></html>
```

test2.html

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a test 2.</p>

</body></html>
```

Comment: you have to connect the signal with the slot. `self.webEngineView.connect.onLoadFinished(slot)` or smt like this

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just read another similar situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125414/how-to-use-webengineview-sethtml-twice-in-pyqt5

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
import threading


class Worker(QObject):
    htmlChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def execute(self, html):
        threading.Thread(target=self.task, daemon=True, args=([html])).start()

    def task(self, html):
        self.htmlChanged.emit(html)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def update_content(self):
        html = self.loadPage2()
        self.worker.execute(html)

    def initUI(self):
        self.worker = Worker(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("update")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.update_content)
        
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
        self.webEngineView.setHtml(self.loadPage())
        
        self.worker.htmlChanged.connect(self.webEngineView.setHtml)

        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.webEngineView)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('QWebEngineView')
        self.show()

    def loadPage(self):
        with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
        return html

    def loadPage2(self):
        with open('test2.html', 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
        return html


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).